# How to set custom texture in custom GPUImage filter?

Tags: objective-c, gpuimage

I have a custom filter builded with GPUImageFilter which has two texture samplers in the shader. The first texture is defined as inputImageTexture in the .fsh file which is bind as default. But I don't know how to bind inputImageTexture2 in code.
I searched the GPUImageFilter.h .m file, but have not found any method related to that. Anyone knows?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use two textures as inputs, subclass or use GPUImageTwoInputFilter instead of GPUImageFilter. The former has all the code set up properly to take in two inputs, and defines the uniform needed for that second texture input.

Otherwise, you could look at what GPUImageTwoInputFilter defines to be able to provide that second texture input and use that yourself in a custom class.